# How to merge/combine two variables in to one variable in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I've been trying to merge/combine two variables into a single one (different one as : var1+var2 = merged into var3)
I am trying to create a for_each loop on the code and my variables are :

```
variable "apps" {
  type = map(object({
    app_name    = string
    labels      = map(string)
    annotations = map(string)
    image       = string
  }))
  default = {
    "app1_name" = {
      app_name = "app1_name"

      labels = {
        "name"  = "stream-frontend"
        "tier"  = "web"
        "owner" = "product"
      }

      annotations = {
        "serviceClass"       = "web-frontend"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "external"
      }
      image = "nxinx"
    }
    "app2_name" = {
      app_name = "app2_name"

      labels = {
        "name"  = "stream-frontend"
        "tier"  = "web"
        "owner" = "product"
      }

      annotations = {
        "serviceClass"       = "web-frontend"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "external"
      }
            image = "nginx"
      }
    
    "app3_name" = {
      app_name = "app3_name"

      labels = {
        "name"  = "stream-database"
        "tier"  = "shared"
        "owner" = "product"
      }

      annotations = {
        "serviceClass"       = "disabled"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "disabled"
      }
            image = "Mongo"
      }
    }
  }

variable "acl" {
  type = map(object({
    acl_name = string
    ingress  = string
    egress   = string
    port     = string
    protocol = string
  }))
  default = {
    "frontend" = {

      acl_name = "acl_frontend"
      ingress  = "stream-frontend"
      egress   = "0.0.0.0/0"
      port     = "80"
      protocol = "TCP"

    },
    "backend" = {

      acl_name   = "acl_backend"
      ingress    = "stream-backend"
      egress     = "0.0.0.0/0"
      port       = "80"
      "protocol" = "TCP"
    },
    "database" = {

      acl_name   = "acl_database"
      "ingress"  = "stream-database"
      "egress"   = "172.17.0.0/24"
      "port"     = "27017"
      "protocol" = "TCP"
    }
  }
}
```

Making a for_each loop to access values of the variables etc.

```
resource "kubernetes_network_policy" "acl" { 
  for_each = var.merged_vars

  metadata {
    name      = format("%s-acl", each.value.acl_name)
    namespace = each.value.acl_name
  }

  spec {
    policy_types = ["Ingress", "Egress"]
    pod_selector {
      match_labels = {

        tier = each.value.labels.tier
      }
    }
    ingress {
      from {
        namespace_selector {
          match_labels = {
            name = each.value.ingress
          }
        }
      }
      ports {
        port     = each.value.port
        protocol = each.value.protocol
      }
    }
    egress {
      to {
        ip_block {
          cidr = each.value.egress
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

eventually I need to have a way to access the "apps" and "acl" parameters as "var.apps.labels" and "var.acl.port" etc.
thank you for your help!

been trying:

```
variable "merged_vars" {
  default = merge(var.apps, var.acl)
}
```

and the result i got is :
│ Error: Function calls not allowed
│
│   on NewVars.tf line 96, in variable "merged_vars":
│   96:   default = merge(var.apps, var.acl)
│
│ Functions may not be called here.

alo tried with concat and got the same result

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you can't create dynamic variables. But you can create [local](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals#when-to-use-local-values) variables dynamically. So you can do:

```
locals {
  merged_vars = merge(var.apps, var.acl)
}
```

And for the `for_each`  you will use local:

```
for_each = local.merged_vars
```

Comment: Do I put the local in the variable section or resource section?

Comment: @zolo Its fully separate block. Check TF docs on locals which I linked.

Comment: hey i've tried it but when i do ``` namespace = each.value.labels.name ```
or something with each.value it does not give me an option to operate

Comment: @zolo For the new issue please make new question. My answer correctly addresses your current error and problem.