# Regex syntax error on a terraform resource metadata

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I have a regex error on the following code:

**the code:**

```
resource "kubernetes_pod" "kube_usage" {
  for_each = var.apps
  metadata {
    name = "${each.value.app_name}-pod"
    labels = {
      app = each.value.app_name
    }
  }

  spec {
    container {
      name  = each.value.app_name
      image = each.value.image
      resources {
        limits = {
          cpu    = "500m"
          memory = "512Mi"
        }
        requests = {
          cpu    = "200m"
          memory = "256Mi"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the error:

```
 Error: metadata.0.name a lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
│
│   with kubernetes_pod.kube_usage["app2_name"],
│   on resources .tf line 4, in resource "kubernetes_pod" "kube_usage":
│    4:   name = "${each.value.app_name}-pod"
```

have tried to implement regex into the code but did not succeed

Comment: This is no related to the regex, rather the name you are providing is probably uppercase or there are some characters which are not allowed in `each.value.app_name`.

Answer (score 0):

as @Marko E said "This is no related to the regex, rather the name you are providing is probably uppercase or there are some characters which are not allowed in each.value.app_name"

the problem what with the "app_name" for the reason my app called: "app1_name" and this syntax is wrong.

Comment: Not Luke though, but always happy to help. :)

Comment: i was on a different page im sorry haha

Comment: No worries, it is important you got to resolve your issue.

Comment: thank you so much and if you could just check this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75092953/how-to-merge-combine-two-variables-in-to-one-variable-in-terraform) i just can't figure the for_each from a local after merging vars.. thank you